# How to click a JavaStaticText using QTP?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

*(Rewritten to focus on the problem and add the real code sample from the comments.)*

I need to click a JavaStaticText object using QTP. Using either of the following 2 lines:

```
JavaWindow("").JavaStaticText("to_class:=JavaStaticText", "index:=12").Click 1, 59, "LEFT"
'OR
JavaWindow("").JavaStaticText("to_class:=JavaStaticText", "index:=12").Click 1, 59
```

...results in:

> Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment:
>   'jWin.JavaStaticText(...).Click
>
> Incorrect expression

The "Exist" method returns true using the same description, so the problem appears to be with the "Click" method.

Real code sample:

```
Set jWin = JavaWindow("label:=Xangati General Dashboard.*")
'This can be clicked:
jWin.JavaStaticText("label:=Appliance", "index:=0").Click 31, 3, "LEFT"
'This gives the syntax errors:
jWin.JavaStaticText("to_class:=JavaStaticText", "index:=12").Click 1, 59, "LEFT"
```

Comment: Is there any more specific detail other than "syntax error"?

Comment: Aside from the "JawaWindow" already mentioned by Xiaofu (which I assume is a typo since you said the 'Exist' method (instead of 'Click') worked just fine, the syntax of your statement you posted here is accurate.  Perhaps there's another typo in your real code that you didn't replicate here?  If you have used 'RegisterUserFunc' to replace the default 'Click' behavior of JavaStaticText, you could have an error in that code.  Otherwise, I suggest you post the real code you're using.  I think the community can appreciate you keeping it concise, but the real code here would help.

Comment: @onkar I have rewritten your question to focus on the problem and added the real code sample from the comments, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Thats fine Xiaofu.... Thanks
Currently i have recoded that particular step for further execution. X & Y co ordinate which I have mentioned are taken from recorded step so there should not be any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is this exactly the code you are using? Your example above says "JawaWindow" as opposed to "JavaWindow". That would certainly give you a syntax error. Presumably you are also passing in a definition for your JavaWindow object...

**Update:**
Is your JavaStaticText very tall? Are the "1, 59" coordinates valid and within the bounds of the JavaStaticText?

The documentation states "IMPORTANT. You must enter valid x- and y-coordinates." but does not state the consequences of invalid coordinates.

Comment: If only there wasn't a minimum character count, I could shout "Utinni!".

Comment: Thanks for reply..Sorry..it was a type mistake
My code is

Comment: Sorry..it was a type mistake
I have explained my issue in 2 comments
My real code is

Set jWin=JavaWindow("label:=Xangati General Dashboard.*")
jWin.JavaStaticText("label:=Appliance","index:=0").Click 31,3,"LEFT"

jWin.JavaStaticText("to_class:=JavaStaticText","index:=12").click 1,59,"LEFT"

"Core parameter" is a JavaStaticText which i am not able to click. There is one more JavaStaticText [Appliance] on same page which i was able to click.I applied same logic for 'core parameter' text but it didnt work.

Comment: EXIST & HIGHLIGHT method work successfully for that line but when I apply 'CLICK' method then i get following error below 'Value' column

<Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: 'jWin.JavaStaticText(...).click'>

& Under 'Type Name' column i got following error
"Incorrect expression"